# Laravel Many to Many Pivot on existing Pivot

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have a situation in Laravel 5.1 where I would like to add a many-to-many relationship to an existing relationship. According to the diagram below, I already have all the items in green working.

[image: Diagram]

The issue is that since there isn't a primary key on the `issue_person` table, I don't know how to add a many-to-many relationship to Users. Does anyone know how I would go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that a simple answer to this is to write a migration that adds a primary key to the original `issue_person` pivot table, and then set up a many-to-many relationship between `issue_person` and `user` using the `position_user` table.

My migration looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('issue_person', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('issue_person', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('id');
    });
}
```